# Why use Pushed Authorization Request if PCKE use is recommended for attack prevention?

Tags: oauth-2.0, pkce

Trying to determine the utility of the OAuth 2.0 Pushed Authorization Request [[RFC9126]](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9126).

Under the Security Consideration section, the RFC talks about a [Request URI Swapping](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9126#name-request-uri-swapping) attack which states:

> Clients **SHOULD** make use of PKCE ... to prevent this attack.

If a Client is going to use PKCE anyway, the only benefit I could see to using a PAR as well is having a slightly reduced payload to give to a browser, for instance.

Are there additional benefits I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

One benefit is that the client backend authenticates itself before authentication is allowed to begin, via a POST request:

```
POST https://login.example.com/authorize/par

client_id=myclient&
client_secret=mysecret&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F&
scope=openid%20profile&
response_type=code&
response_mode=jwt&
code_challenge=l9QIPE4TFgW2y7STZDSWQ4Y4CQpO8W6VtELopzYHdNg&
code_challenge_method=S256&
state=NlAoISfdL1DxPdNGFBljlVuB1GDjgGARmqDcxtHhV8iKNYu6ECS2KOavDHpI3eLN
```

Another benefit is that the browser request sent on the front channel is protected against tampering. eg by a `man in the browser`:

```
https://login.example.com/authorize?
client_id=mylient&
request_uri=urn:ietf:params:oauth:request_uri:7d353fc8-9b94-488f-8c61-cf7cc1dfef9e"
```

Note that PKCE continues to be used and a `code_verifier` is sent later, to get tokens. This proves that the party finishing authentication is the one that started it, as is standard.